# Boolean list operation in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, boolean, boolean-logic

Shouldn't the results be the same?
I do not understand.

```
[True,False] and [True, True]
Out[1]: [True, True]

[True, True] and [True,False]
Out[2]: [True, False]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What? Shouldn't these list be `and`ed value-wise?

Comment: [a and b for a, b in zip(x, y)], that is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because that's not the way that `and` operation works in python. First off it doesn't `and` the list items separately. Secondly the `and` operator works between two objects and if one of them is False ([evaluated as False](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) <sup>1</sup>) it returns that and if both are True it returns the second one. Here is an example :

```
>>> [] and [False]
[]
>>> 
>>> [False] and []
[]
>>> [False] and [True]
[True]
```

> `x and y` :   if `x` is false, then `x`, else `y`

If you want to apply the logical operations on all the lists pairs you can use numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([True, False])
>>> b = np.array([True, True])
>>> 
>>> np.logical_and(a,b)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_and(b,a)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

<sub>1. Here since you are dealing with lists an empty list will be evaluated as False</sub>

Comment: [a and b for a, b in zip(x, y)], thanks, that also works